# Best way to read and process a large data files >0.5GB in C

Tags: c, performance, csv, large-files

I need to write code in C which could read large csv files containing large matrix of data with `double` values. I have to read column by column and I have no prior information about the number of rows and columns in the file.
What is the most efficient way to process it in C language - in terms of both time and memory? I basically need to process each column separately but can do with reading row wise if it is more efficient to read.

Please direct me to the answer if it has been asked before.
Thanks

Comment: If I were you, I would consider [memory mapped file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

Comment: It depends what you need to do with the data. If you only need to sum or average the nth column, say, there is no need to read the entire file into memory in one go, you can read a line at a time and do a running total.

Answer (score 0):

A csv file is a text file. Usually, each row is separated by end-of-line characters and commas separate the columns. You have to scan each line to identify columns.

There are lots of ways to solve this. Your solution really depends on the routines you are comfortable using.

I would allocate as big a buffer as you can afford using malloc(), read the csv file in in chunks using fread(), and scan through it to find and process the columns.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

// JFL 11 Feb 15
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   int r;
   int allocsize,filesize,len;
   char *fname;
   char *alloc=0;
   FILE *fh=0;

   if(argc<2)
      goto BAIL;
   fname=argv[1];

   // open file, find size
   if(!(fh=fopen(fname,"rb")))
      goto BAIL;
   fseek(fh,0,SEEK_END); // seek to end
   if((filesize=ftell(fh))<0)
      goto BAIL;
   fseek(fh,0,SEEK_SET);

   // alloc buffer
   allocsize=16*1024; // max buffer size
   if(allocsize>filesize)
      allocsize=filesize; // limit to filesize

   // 'search' for the largest buffer we can use temporarily
   for(;allocsize>1024;allocsize-=1024)
   {
      if((alloc=malloc(allocsize)))
         break; // allocated
   } // for

   if(!alloc)
   { // try once more, small buffer
      allocsize=1024;
      if(!(alloc=malloc(allocsize)))
         goto BAIL;
   }

   // read the file
   for(;filesize;)
   {
      len=filesize; // remaining size
      if(len>allocsize)
         len=allocsize; // limit to buffer size
      if(len!=fread(alloc,1,len,fh)) // read
         goto BAIL;
      filesize-=len; // adjust remaining size

      // process len bytes
   } // for

   r=ftell(fh);

   printf("success, read %d bytes\n",r);
BAIL: // common exit point
   if(fh)
      fclose(fh); // close if opened
   if(alloc)
      free(alloc); // free if allocated
   return 0;
} // main()
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe. Is there a way to know how big a buffer I can afford? I have 16gb of RAM though.

Comment: how ever big size buffer you allocate, the system reads page by page, example, 4kb ~ 4096, so performance wise , it still the same.

Answer (score 0):

As csv is row-based (line-based) and you need to process columns, the best way would be to take the whole file in memory: ask the filesize and allocagte that chunk of memory with malloc. Read the first line and determine the number of columns, 'numcols'. Now reprocess the file and allocate for each line an array with 'numcols' entries that will point to the start of the column in the line (as each number can have a different number of digits, you may not assume all columns start at the same offset in the line). Now you are ready to process your columns.

If the file does not fit in memory, you can open 'numcols' additional output files into which you write the columns from the lines of the input (e.g. you write doubles in binary format to the files), then rewind them and process each file, which holds a column. If these output files fit in memory, you can read them in into an array. (I didn't say this is efficient.)